# Convert DropDownList to CheckBoxList in Yii

Tags: checkbox, drop-down-menu, yii, frameworks, yii-extensions

Im a beginner with Yii Framework.
I have a lot of dropdownList in my search form and i want to convert them to cheboxList but i don't know how to proceed?

For Example this is the view code of one of the DropdownList

```
. '<div class="row" style="width:100%;">'
        . CHtml::encode('Pet')
        //. CHtml::textField('HotelType', (isset($_GET['HotelType'])) ? $_GET['HotelType'] : '', array('id'=>'HotelType'))

               . CHtml::dropDownList('Pet', 'pet_id', array(
                    ''=>'All',
                    'Y'=>'Yes',
                    'N'=>'No',
            ),array(
                //'options' => (isset($_GET['HotelType'])) ? $_GET['HotelType'] : array('studio'=>array('selected'=>true), array($_GET['HotelType']=>array('selected'=>true)))
                'options' => array($_GET['Pet']=>array('selected'=>true)),
                'style' => 'width:100%;'
            ))
        . '</div>'
```

what kind of modifications should I do (in view, controller and model if necessary) to transfome the dropdown into a checkbox ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the view you need to change dropDownList to checkBoxList() http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#checkBoxList-detail

Then in the controller, depending on what you are trying to do with the selection, adjust the method to receive the multiple options.

Then pass them to the model to either update a DB record or be used in an SQL query to return the data.

Comment: thank you for the reply,
can you please show and explain me how to do please ?

Comment: Read the document on checkboxlist. And as for the controller/model work, you haven't said what you're trying to do, provided code, or tried something to see how to do it

Comment: all what I want to do is replace the dropdownlist by checkbos but I don't know how and what to do. can you please help im beginner with yii

Comment: @Mushroom, read what Jonnny is saying again. Read the document, then come back and update your question with a specific problem you have.